# Showing that three systems define the same behaviour

Tags: systems-of-equations, control-theory

I have three input/state/output representations of the form

$$\begin{cases}\frac{d}{dt}x=Ax+Bu \\ y=Cx\end{cases}$$

with the three systems given by:

$$A_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix} B_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} C_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} B_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} C_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} B_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} C_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to show that these **three** systems define the same i/o behaviour.

There is a theorem which says that **two** state space representations are input/output equivalent (i.e. define the same behaviour) if $\exists$ a non-singular matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $PA_{1}P^{-1}=A_{2}$, $PB_{1}=B_{2}$ and $C_{1}P^{-1}=C_{2}$.

I took $P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and then, after performing the computations I found that the first system defined the same behaviour as the second system.

Now, I would appreciate some help with showing this is true for all three systems.

I think I can write the i/s/o representation in the form

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{y}=\frac{AC}{y}+Bu$$

Since $x=\frac{C}{y}\implies\frac{d}{dt}x=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{y}$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The states of the three systems do not have the same behavior as the third system has a zero eigenvalue while the first two systems have eigenvalues in -1, -2. I guess what you are looking after is the same input/output behavior.

Comment: @CTNT Yes, sorry; that was what I meant.

Comment: This means that there does not exist invertible transformation $P$ such that $PA_1P^{-1}=A_3$ (different inertia). But it's easy to  prove that $$C_ie^{A_it}B_i=C_je^{A_jt}B_j \qquad\forall i,j=1,2,3$$ which corresponds to the same output response for zero initial conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third system does not have the same behavior with the first two. But they have the same input/output behavior, i.e. they have the same transfer function. You can calculate the transfer function as

$$ G(s) = C (sI - A)^{-1} B $$

which will give the same result for the three systems above. It is due to the fact that the eigenvalue -2 in the first two systems and 0 in the third system is not controllable (it is also not observable but only one of them is enough for not to see it in the transfer function).

Comment: I actually get that $G_{1}(s)=G_{2}(s)=\frac{1}{3}$, but $G_{3}(s)=1$.

Comment: For the first system $G_1(s) = C (sI - A)^{-1}B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}s+1 & 0 \\ 0 & s+2\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{s+1} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{s+2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{s+1} $. You can calculate others similarly.